# Should I delete one question with many downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Should I delete one question with many downvotes? and after editing, then I　post one new question?

Because I found that, some people downvoted a question will not redo the downvote even the OP have edited it a better question.

Comment: See [Should I delete and repost my question to regenerate interest?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3795/264).

Comment: Also see [Re-asking a question to get rid of a negative score](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10024/re-asking-a-question-to-get-rid-of-a-negative-score).

Comment: @Ataraxia Would you care to expand on your comment? :p

Comment: @user1729 Wow, I don't know how that happened, I must have hit enter by mistake and not realized it. What I was going to say is, why is it that both questions are basically the same thing, but one has 9 net votes, and the other has -5?

Comment: @Ataraxia: I would say it's because wanting to generate interest in your post is reasonable, but wanting to prevent criticism of your post and/or wanting avoid losing points is petty.

Comment: @ZevC (I am not wanting to drag up and old post but...) The question "Re-asking a question to get rid of a negative score" was not about an individual user's points, but rather about a highly-downvoted question which was actually a very good question and would have received a respectable score (perhaps edging into the >10 area) if only it had been posed well initially. (It was a whopping +0/-7 originally! It is now +20/-5.)